# I can't get the js response in variable that say is null

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, axios

When I connect axion in get method I get a response from my api and I want to print info on the website.

I tried to change this line:

```
 .then(response => (this.username= response.data.username)) or this
 .then(response => (this.username= response.data[0].username)) or this 
 .then(response => (this.username= response.data.username[0]))
```

Script

```
<script>
   import axios from 'axios';

   export default {
     name: "acount",
     el: '#app',
     data() {
       return {
         username: null,
         pseudo: null,
         email: null,
         date: null,
       };
   },
   mounted () {
     axios
      .get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/user/65', {
      headers: {
      token: ''
      }
  })
    .then(response => (this.username= response.data[0].username[0]))
    .then(response => (this.pseudo = response.data.pseudo))
    .then(response => (this.email = response.data.email))
    .then(response => (this.date = response.data.create_at))
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. The question should contain clear problem statement. The title is unintelligible. Please, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

To chain promises, each function within then() needs to return a value. other than that we could only help, if we would know how the actual response looks like.

```js
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

  setTimeout(() => resolve(1), 1000); // (*)

}).then(function(result) { // (**)

  alert(result); // 1
  return result * 2;

}).then(function(result) { // (***)

  alert(result); // 2
  return result * 2;

}).then(function(result) {

  alert(result); // 4
  return result * 2;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This arrow function uses implicitly returned value:

```
.then(response => (this.username= response.data[0].username[0]))
```

This results in having `response` parameter in next `then` equal to `this.username`. To avoid such mistakes, ESLint [`no-return-assign`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-assign) rule can be used.

Instead, it should be:

```
.then(response => {
  this.username= response.data[0].username[0];
  return response;
})
```

Multiple `then` are unnecessary because there are no multiple promises to chain. They could be rewritten to single `then`:

```
 axios.get(...)
    .then(response => {
        this.username= response.data[0].username[0]);
        ...
    });
```